# java.text.SimpleDateFormat#parse has different behaviour between Scala and Clojure

Tags: java, scala, datetime, clojure

I'm trying to assign `PDT` string to `java.util.Date` using `SimpleDateFormat`.

**Scala, gives me the right format which is `PDT` (`UTC-07:00`)**, with or without setting timeZone as my os timeZone is `"America/Los_Angeles"`.

```
scala> import java.util.TimeZone
import java.util.TimeZone

scala> import java.util.Date
import java.util.Date

scala> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

scala> TimeZone.getDefault
res0: java.util.TimeZone = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]

scala> val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
df: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@fe8c5ede

scala> df.parse("2017-10-28T23:59:59-07:00")
res1: java.util.Date = Sat Oct 28 23:59:59 PDT 2017
```

**But Clojure parses date in UTC format (`:UTC-00:00`),**

without `.setTimeZone`,

```
aws-creds.core=> (import 'java.util.TimeZone)
java.util.TimeZone

aws-creds.core=> (TimeZone/getDefault)
#object[sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo 0x28ce2a1 "sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"America/Los_Angeles\",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]"]

aws-creds.core=> (import 'java.util.Date)
java.util.Date

aws-creds.core=> (import 'java.text.SimpleDateFormat)
java.text.SimpleDateFormat

aws-creds.core=> (let [df (new SimpleDateFormat "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX" )]
            #_=>   (print (.parse df "2017-10-28T23:59:59-07:00")))
#inst "2017-10-29T06:59:59.000-00:00"nil
```

Same behaviour with `.setTimeZone` to `America/Los_Angeles`,

```
aws-creds.core=> (let [df (new SimpleDateFormat "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX" )]
            #_=>   (.setTimeZone df (TimeZone/getTimeZone "America/Los_Angeles"))
            #_=>   (print (.parse df "2017-10-28T23:59:59-07:00")))
#inst "2017-10-29T06:59:59.000-00:00"nil
```

which is strange, since in both cases I'm using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. Curious why `SimpleDateFormat#parse` scala stores date in `PDT` format while clojure in `UTC` format?

Comment: Are you sure they're not configured differently? Or running in different environments?

Comment: All config is posted above which is similar unless I'm doing something stupid. Both are in the same OS. you can see `TimeZone/getDefault` for both scala and clojure

Comment: Your posted example shows results out of order and  the wrong format string.

Comment: @som-snytt are you talking about `res13` and `res12`?? `TimeZone` is same anyway

Comment: OK more explicitly, if you show code that doesn't work, we can't help you. This `"yyyy:MM:dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"` is not what you're parsing.

Comment: @som-snytt thanks, I was stupid to copy paste wrong thing. its corrected now.

Comment: That's OK. Obviously, I tried your transcript. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the Clojure REPL simply prints dates in UTC.

If you call `toString()` on the date, it prints the date exactly as the Scala REPL (which I believe implicitly calls toString when printing objects) does, and in the system time zone:

```
user=> (let [df (new SimpleDateFormat "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX" )]
  #_=>   (print (.toString (.parse df "2017-10-28T23:59:59-07:00"))))
Sat Oct 28 23:59:59 PDT 2017nil
```